# How to check 2 Dimensional array for a winner in a game of tic tac toe

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I am creating a game of tic tac toe as a project with a 2dimensional array and I am having some trouble checking the spots to see if there is a winner. Can someone help me debug this? Here is the checkwinner function and the main function.

```
char CheckWinner( char board[3][3])
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

                    if ( board[i][j] =='X' && board[i][j+1] == 'X' && board[i][j+2]== 'X' )
                    { W = X;}
                    else if (board[i+1][j] && board[i+1][i+1] && board[i+1][j+2]== 'X' )
                    { W = X;}
                    else if (board[i+2][j] && board[i+2][j+1] && board[i+2][j+2]== 'X')
                    { W = X;}
                    else if (board[i][j] && board[i+1][j] && board[i+2][j]== 'X')
                    { W = X;}
                    else if (board[i][j+1] && board[i+1][j+1] && board[i+2][j+1]== 'X')
                    { W = X;}
                    else if (board[i][j+2] && board[i+1][j+2] && board[i+2][j+2]== 'X')
                    { W =X;}
                    else if (board[i][j] && board[i+1][j+1] && board[i+2][j+2]=='X')
                    { W = X;}
                    else if (board[i+2][j] && board[i+1][j+1] && board[i][j+2]== 'X')
                    { W = X;}

                    else if (board[i][j] && board[i][j+1] && board[i][j+2]== 'O' )
                    { W = O;}
                    else if (board[i+1][j] && board[i+1][j+1] && board[i+1][j+2]== 'O')
                    { W = O;}
                    else if (board[i+2][j] && board[i+2][j+1] && board[i+2][j+2]== 'O')
                    { W = O;}
                    else if (board[i][j] && board[i+1][j] && board[i+2][j]== 'O')
                    { W = O;}
                    else if (board[i][j+1] && board[i+1][j+1] && board[i+2][j+1]== 'O')
                    { W = O;}
                    else if (board[i][j+2] && board[i+1][j+2] && board[i+2][j+2]== 'O')
                    { W = O;}
                    else if (board[i][j] && board[i+1][j+1] && board[i+2][j+2]== 'O')
                    { W = O;}
                    else if (board[i+2][j] && board[i+1][j+1] && board[i][j+2]== 'O')
                    { W = O;}



    return W;
}
int main () 
{ 
    char board[3][3];
    char Win = CheckWinner(board);
    int r = 0;


    InitializeBoard(board);

     for (int r = 0; r < 4 ; r++)
     { 
        PlayX(board);
        PlayO(board); 
        PrintBoard(board);
    }
     CheckWinner(board);
     cout << Win ;

    if (Win == X)
    {
        cout << "The winner is Player 1.";
    }
    else if (Win == O)
    {
        cout << "The winner is Player 2.";
    }
    else if (Win == TIE)
    {
        cout << " IT'S A TIE";
    }
    else; 


    system("PAUSE");
return 0;
```

Comment: Debug what, exactly? What's the error/bug you're getting?

Comment: Please include the exact error message.

Comment: Okay I stopped the error message. That was a trivial typo up above in another function.Sorry.

Comment: I presume "stopped the error message" means it's fixed.  Voting to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You immediately assign the `CheckWinner` result to `Win`, then play the game out, then call `CheckWinner` again without assigning its result to `Win`. Thus when you check `Win` in the following line, you have the original result from when the board wasn't even initialized.

Comment: This is suppose to check the 8 different ways you can win for x and o.

Comment: An answer that ends with a question? Should this be a comment?

Comment: Disregard that. Your first suggestion makes me feel so dumb, I should have realized that earlier. That makes my game work, so everything was right I just didn't assign Win to CheckWinner at the correct location. Thank You.

Answer (score 3):

You can optimize your conditional code with the following:

```
typedef char piece;

piece iswin() const
{
    piece ret = 'T';

    // Checks for horizontal win
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        if (*arr[i] == arr[i][1] && arr[i][1] == arr[i][2])
            if ((ret = *arr[i]) != 'T')
                return ret;

    // Checks for vertical win
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        if (arr[0][i] == arr[1][i] && arr[1][i] == arr[2][i])
            if ((ret = arr[0][i]) != 'T')
                return ret;

    // Check for diagonal win (upper left to bottom right)
    if (**arr == arr[1][1] && arr[1][1] == arr[2][2])
        if ((ret = **arr) != 'T')
            return ret;

    // Check for diagonal win (upper right to bottom left)
    if (arr[0][2] == arr[1][1] && arr[1][1] == arr[2][0])
        if ((ret = arr[0][2]) != 'T')
            return ret;

    return ret;
}

// checking the result:
switch (winner) {
    case 'T': /* tie */ break;
    case 'X': /* X won */ break;
    case 'O': /* O won */ break;
}
```

This is little bit cleaner. And it does 6 loops instead of 9.

Comment: @Armin, yeah thanks. Fixed. I must have been drunk when I wrote this.

Answer (score 0):

Probably has to do with assigning a literal O or X into a return value that is supposed to be a char.  Thus instead of O or X it should be 'O' or 'X'. Unless O or X is defined as a char variable outside the posted code.

Comment: const char X = 'X' and const char O = 'O' I've tried it both ways.